# How to read a specific type of json data

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

here is my sample json data

```
{"Caption":"BBA Feedback Form ","Notes":"Fields marked with \u003cfont size=\"-2\"  color=\"#e30102\" face=\"Verdana\"\u003e&nbsp;(*)&nbsp;\u003c/font\u003e are  compulsory","Name":"Name\u003cfont size=\"-2\" color=\"#e30102\" face=\"Verdana\"\u003e&nbsp;*&nbsp;\u003c/font\u003e","Subject":"Subject\u003cfont size=\"-2\" color=\"#e30102\" face=\"Verdana\"\u003e&nbsp;*&nbsp;\u003c/font\u003e","Email":"Email Address\u003cfont size=\"-2\" color=\"#e30102\" face=\"Verdana\"\u003e&nbsp;*&nbsp;\u003c/font\u003e","Details":"Feedback\u003cfont size=\"-2\" color=\"#e30102\" face=\"Verdana\"\u003e& nbsp;*&nbsp;\u003c/font\u003e"}
```

i want to parse it with jquery and fill my label. i tried like this below way but things did not work.

```
    function LoadEnquiryData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlToHandler + "?ac=show",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("input[id*='enq_lblcaption']").val(data["Caption"])
            $("input[id*='enq_lblnotes']").val(data["Notes"])
            $("input[id*='enq_lblfield_name']").val(data["Name"])
            $("input[id*='enq_lblfield_subject']").val(data["Subject"])
            $("input[id*='enq_lblfield_email']").val(data["Email"])
            $("input[id*='txtEnqDetails']").val(data["Details"])
            $("input[id*='btnEnqSubmit']").val(data["SubmitVal"])

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

so please guide me how to parse it. thanks

Comment: " i tried like this below way but things did not work." how do you know that it didn't work? any errors? ..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[id*='enq_lblcaption']").val(data.Caption)
$("input[id*='enq_lblnotes']").val(data.Notes)
and so on...
```

My bad, you don't need parseJSON for this - I was already working with it for something else and just popped it in here. I've edited my code above and this should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd include a bit more than "didn't work" to help (like what error you get), but from what you have I don't see anything that stands out wrong.  From the json, you can access your fields two way:

The first, you have it like `data["Caption"]`
or the second, like `Data.Caption`

I'd verify your data that comes back to ensure it matches the sample you provided. It's possible the you may be getting an array of those objects?  It's hard to tell with out the server code that returns your data.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `data` variable is not `null` or `undefined`?

I am telling this because your logic is correct. Also, there are two ways to get your `data` by doing the following:

```
data["Caption"]
```

or

```
data.Caption
```

*(do the same for other values)*

But seems strange that you can't do that. If you want to test what I am telling you, go here:

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/6NUNd/

And look how your `json` gets parsed without problems only when `data` is not `null` or `undefined`.

---

I will suggest you to print your `data` variable first doing `console.log(data);` and take a look if your `$.ajax callback` is working properly.

---

Hope this helps :-)